# Sphinx search configuration for words ending with apostrophes

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to improve my Sphinx configuration and I have a trouble with words ending with apostrophes.

For example, for Surfin' USA result, searching with "Surfin USA" returns match but "Surfing USA" doesn't return anything. How can I set Sphinx to return result for such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, thats an interesting one. Not sure sphinx can automatically deal with this, because it has no way of knowing what the Apostrophe is meant to represent. I suppose there are cases where it could be multiple things.

The only way I can think would be to list them in exceptions, you can build a list of all words want to support

```
Surfin' > Surfing
```

Have to use exceptions to be able to use the apostrophe

You might want to add

```
Surfin > Surfing
```

too, so can search without the apostrophe too.

Comment: Thank you very much Barry, you wrote "exceptions" but also there is a thing called "wordforms" and I guess it's more suitable because it looks case insensitive. What's your recommendation about that? Which one should I choose?

Comment: Wordforms would require you to put ' in charset_table. You might be happy to do that, but figured not.